# lighttpd complains about ssl.use-compression

Tags: ssl, compression, https, tls, lighttpd

I am trying to apply some of the tricks described [here](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_lighttpd.html), and the problem is having `ssl.use-compression = "disable"` in `lighttpd.conf`, because server reports `WARNING: unknown config-key: ssl.use-compression`. I am a bit confused, since I cannot find any reference to this option. I also tried including `mod_compress`, but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is default since lighttpd (1.4.28-2+squeeze1.1):
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=700399

Comment: To clarify, SSL compression is now disabled at compile time and so the config option has been removed.